# Plane is rotating as it's arrayed on curve

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to array a rectangular plane along a curve, end-to-end, lengthwise.  In the first photo you can see how the plane is oriented to the curve.  When I add the array and curve modifiers, while the plane is arrayed along the curve, it is being rotated about -45 degrees, i.e. not end to end and therefore not a continuous mesh.  Any help appreciated.

[image: Flat plane to be arrayed/extruded along curve]

[image: Plane is incorrectly rotated]

Comment: Don't rotate your plane, keep it aligned with the global axis, it's the curve that will orientate it as it is supposed to. If it still doesn't work, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello moonbots; thank you for that.  It extrudes along the curve now.